# Scope issue in next() callback in Observer

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-material

I am a new to Angular 9. Using Angular Material. I am using [MatSidenavContent](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/api#MatSidenavContent) which has a method called `elementScrolled` which returns a Observable.

I got the observable working with no issues. When I scroll the next() callback fires. But I need to run `this.sideNavContent.measureScrollOffset();` to get the scroll position and `this.sideNavContent` is undefined in the next() callback.

I imagine this is a scope issue. How can I get it to where I can invoke `this.sideNavContent.measureScrollOffset();` when the observer fires?

Also, is there a better to do this observer(since I am new to Angular).

```
  @ViewChild('sideNavContent') public sideNavContent: MatSidenavContent;

  runScroller() {
    const scroller = this.sideNavContent.elementScrolled();

    scroller.subscribe({
      next(foo) {
        const offset = this.sideNavContent.measureScrollOffset();
        console.log(offset);
      },
      error(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
      },
    });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.runScroller();
  }
```

Comment: I suspect the problem might be because the method definition syntax you're using doesn't bind `this` as your enclosing class. If you want to stick to passing the object, try using arrow functions instead (e.g. `next: (foo) => { ... }, error: (msg) => { ... }`), which should implicitly bind `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix the scope issue within subscribe or use operators execute necessary logics. Use the double arrow in operator function should give you the correct scope

```
scroller.pipe(tap(()=>
  {
    const offset = this.sideNavContent.measureScrollOffset();
    console.log(offset);
  }),
  catchError((msg)=>{
    console.log(msg);
    return of(msg);
  }),
).subscribe()
```